# How to connect to iscsi target with iscsiadm from Synology through SSH

Tags: backup, iscsi, synology-diskstation

Since we want to back up our Synology NAS internally with a rotation system, I'm trying to connect to an iscsi target on my tandberg/overland Quickstation 4 from my Synology NAS (SA3400). I've tried using iscsiadm from the command line through SSH since i cannot find a GUI solution for this, but haven't had any luck so far.

When I try to discover using the following command:

```
sudo iscsiadm -m discovery --type sendtargets --portal 192.168.1.1
```

I get the following output:

```
iscsiadm: can not connect to iSCSI daemon (111)!
iscsiadm: can not connect to iSCSI daemon (111)!
iscsiadm: Cannot perform discovery. Initiatorname required.
iscsiadm: Discovery process to 192.168.1.1:3260 failed to create a discovery session.
iscsiadm: Could not perform SendTargets discovery.
```

#### Update:

I got feedback from synology support; they apologize any inconvenience caused and doesn't want to provide any documentation for their system other than what they have on their website. No help from them.

I managed to discover the target (I had to run `iscsid` as sudo su), but I'm stuck because I cannot find a way to get the iscsi_tcp driver to start.
`depmod -a` doesn't work, and `modprobe iscsi_tcp` doesn't do anything as far as I can see, `lsmod | grep iscsi` returns `iscsi_target_mod` and `iscsi_core_mod` only.

Basically, modprobe seems to be totally stripped of functionality on the Synology.

When I try to load the modules with insmod:
`insmod /usr/lib/modules/iscsi_tcp.ko` I get the following error:
`insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /usr/lib/modules/libiscsi_tcp.ko: Unknown symbol in module`

When I try to log in to the target, I get the following:

```
Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.SomeTargetName, portal: 192.168.1.1,3260]
iscsiadm: Could not login to [iface: default, target: iqn.SomeTargetName, portal: 192.168.1.1,3260]:
iscsiadm: initiator reported error (12 - iSCSI driver not found. Please make sure it is loaded, and retry the operation)
```

I'm soon giving up on trying, it is a shame that Synology is unwilling to support such a basic need as this.

So my question now is:

**Is there a solution out there, where I can connect to a target from Synology (most likely through the CLI) and make it persistently logged in and mounted in DSM, even after updates and restarts?**

> Note: the IP is obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I was looking to do today with a RS2418+ running DSM 6.2.4 and I found this post really helpful:

[synology-automount-an-external-iscsi-volume](https://sites.google.com/site/nliaudat/nas/nas---synology/synology-automount-an-external-iscsi-volume)

I have a DroboPro which is full, but I found I could attach it to the RS2418+ and serve the files from there. This is my Task Scheduler script (with some details obfuscated):

```
/usr/syno/etc/rc.iscsi start
iscsiadm -m node --targetname STRING_FROM_ISCSIADM_DISCOVERY --portal IP_ADDRESS --login

while [[ ! $(blkid -s PARTLABEL -o value | grep drobo) ]]
do sleep 30
done

mount PARTLABEL=drobo_1 /volume2
mount PARTLABEL=drobo_2 /volume3
mount PARTLABEL=drobo_3 /volume4

sed -i '$ i\ <space path="\/dev\/isda2" reference="\/volume2"><device><\/device><reference><volume path="\/volume2" dev_path="\/dev\/isda2" type="ext3"><\/volume><\/reference><\/space>' /tmp/space/space_mapping.xml

sleep 5

synoshare --add MY_SHARED_FOLDER "MY_SHARED_FOLDER" /volume2/MY_SHARED_FOLDER "" "MY_USERNAME,ANOTHER_USERNAME,@administrators,admin,guest" "" 1 0
```

Note that this is a very permissive setup for a general folder that anyone on the network can read and write to!